# How to show progress in a search input using angular material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I created an application which contains material input for search purpose.
I would like the horizontal line of the input field to have progress indicator, when search is in progress.
My idea is to show and hide progressBar with *ngIf and move it with css to match te input horizontal line height.
Here is the code:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
   <input matInput (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
   <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="searchDone" style="top:9px" [color]='color' mode="query"></mat-progress-bar>
</mat-form-field>
```

I dont think it is the best solution, because I see the input horizontal line under the progressbar.
Is there any solution that makes the input horizontal line to show progress by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one possible solution you can start using the lib [NgxMatSelectSearch](https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search).

The [Api](https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search#api) has an input option `searching` to display an indicator while searching.

See the example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-select-search) and try to search in "Server side search" input.

Answer (score 1):

You can position the progress bar over the form field with a template like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="message" [matTextareaAutosize]="true" [matAutosizeMinRows]="1" [placeholder]="placeholder"></textarea>
        <button (click)="create()" mat-icon-button matSuffix matTooltip="Send" [disabled]="creating">
            <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="creating"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

and css like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

mat-progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
}
```